# Why did Caleb wait so long to take charge of Hebron & Debir?

Tags: shoftim--book-of, joshua--book-of, yehoshua-joshua, kaleb-caleb

In [Joshua 14:6-14](https://bible.oremus.org/?ql=535653548), we read that, after spending 7 years in the land, Caleb was allotted Hebron at his request. [Judges 1:1-15](https://bible.oremus.org/?ql=535653548) informs us that Caleb and Othniel's conquest didn't take place until after Joshua's death. Caleb's request, especially verses [11-12](https://bible.oremus.org/?ql=535653548), appears quite enthusiastic about acquiring that land. Why, then, does he wait 21 years to go through with taking charge of his allottment.